# Using NSPredicate with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I'm trying to use the input on an NSTextField along with NSPredicate to populate a NSMutableArray of like objects.

In my app I have the following simple NSMutableArray

```
{
        firstName = Danton;
        phoneNumbers = 5555555555;
}
```

Now, I am using the following code to try and filter the results as the user types (if "Dan" is in the textField, the filtered array should include the above object)

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchField.text];

filteredArray = [[filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Filtered values: %@", filteredArray);
```

However, I am getting an empty return on filteredArray. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You are running the predicate on `filteredArray` which is empty so why would the return not be empty? Run the predicate on a non-empty array.

Comment: well, that was stupid of me. thank you for pointing out my obvious mistake :( now everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSArray *array = @[

          @{
                  @"firstName" : @"Danton", @"phoneNumbers" : @"5555555555"
          }
  ];

  NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", @"firstName", @"Dan"]];
```

Comment: Please explain a bit what is going on here.

Comment: If you want to find some text inside of any object’s properties, you can use a NSPredicate like above. 
I think the problem with the filteredArray is always empty. There is not any objects. You cannot apply a filter.